Sharpe Ratio using Daily Returns or Percent Returns
Say I have a daily PnL series:



Date
PnL




1/1
4


1/2
3


1/3
-1


1/4
5



To calculate the annualized sharpe ratio, can I do: mean(PnL) / std(PnL) * sqrt(252)?
This gets me 16.5.
Alternatively, I've read online people say you need to calculate the returns and do the calculation on the returns. If I do percent change on the cumulative sum series, I would get:



Date
Pct_Change




1/1
NaN


1/2
.75


1/3
-.14


1/4
.83



This gets me 14.085.
Which is correct?

The second one, but more importantly, your time series is way too short.

Why is the first one wrong? (and yes I know the series is too short ha)

The first method is sometimes used for futures trading, where percent return is hard to define and dollar P&L is more natural. However the second method is used in all other cases and agrees with the research literature, including Sharpe's original paper.

"Why is the first one wrong?" suppose you compare the returns of two stocks, one that trades around $1 and one that trades around $100. Would a $1 PnL be comparable in those cases?

You're comparing apples to oranges. If you're using 4-month returns, you need to annualize them for consistency with the annualized standard deviation. Similarly, if you're using annual SD, your returns must also be annualized
import yfinance as yf 
import numpy as np 

data = yf.download("^GSPC", start="2023-01-01", end="2023-12-31")
data['Daily Return'] = data['Adj Close'].pct_change()
cumulative_return = (1 + data['Daily Return']).prod() - 1
std_daily_return = data['Daily Return'].std()
annualized_std = std_daily_return * np.sqrt(252)
risk_free_rate = 0.04 
sharpe_ratio = (cumulative_return - risk_free_rate) / annualized_std


Hi Aditya: If you want a clear explanation of log returns versus arithmetic returns, see this. https://www.sixfigureinvesting.com/2024/10/accurately-forecasting-multi-period-stock-market-returns/
